# What are the supported platform in neutralinojs

Tags: neutralinojs

I am creating desktop app for windows, mac and linux. I am happy to create app in windows but in linux I always encountered so many issues.

Comment: Neutralino will work on Linux, Windows and macOS. Could you update the specific problem on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly, neutralinojs supports every computer OS.

(Linux, Windows, and Mac)

You said you have encountered many issues, you should post those issues under the neutralinojs tag and they will be answered.